# Issue rendering stuff with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My issue appears in my app with a simple calculator that I want to calculate the delivery fee.
The issues is that somehow only the previous number is saved/memorized.
for example I type : 1 (now surcharge is 9) then I type 2 ( surcharge is now 0 and should be 0)
but when I click the button and the surcharge should get added to whatever number( i added 2 in the OverallResult) it uses the previous surcharge value which is 9 so my total becomes 11.
This problem persists throughout the code, I'm sure I have some other issues as well but this one is my main concern.
I want to use useEffect and update data, after the data has been updated I want when clicked to update the total delivery fee and post in the screen.
Here I will post just a code for Surcharge.js and my main app.js + helper.js + OverallResult.
In case someone wants the whole project let me know!

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { MIN_SUR_VALUE, INITIAL_VALUE, FREE_SHIPPING } from "../helper/helper";
function Surcharge(props) {
  const [totalSurcharge, changeTotalSurcharge] = useState(INITIAL_VALUE);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.cartValue <= FREE_SHIPPING) {
      if (props.cartValue < MIN_SUR_VALUE) {
        changeTotalSurcharge(MIN_SUR_VALUE - props.cartValue);
      } else {
        changeTotalSurcharge(INITIAL_VALUE);
      }
    } else {
      changeTotalSurcharge(INITIAL_VALUE);
    }
    return props.changeSurchargeFee(totalSurcharge);

    console.log("props.cartvalue" + totalSurcharge);
  }, [props.cartValue]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>total for delivery{totalSurcharge}</h1>
      <label htmlFor="cartValue">Cart value:</label>
      <input
        value={props.cartValue}
        type="number"
        id="cartValue"
        className="cartValue"
        onChange={(e) => props.changeCartValue(e.target.value)}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Surcharge;

// props.cartValue <= FREE_SHIPPING
//   ? props.cartValue < MIN_SUR_VALUE
//     ? changeTotalSurcharge(MIN_SUR_VALUE - props.cartValue)
//     : changeTotalSurcharge(INITIAL_VALUE)
//   : changeTotalSurcharge(INITIAL_VALUE);
```

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Surcharge from "./components/Surcharge";
import Distance from "./components/Distance";
import NumberOfItems from "./components/NumberOfItems";
import OverallResult from "./components/OverallResult";
import { DATE_RN, RND1 } from "./helper/helper";

function initialValue() {
  return 0;
}

function App() {
  const [cartValue, changeCartValue] = useState(() => initialValue());
  const [deliveryDistance, changeDeliveryDistance] = useState(() =>
    initialValue()
  );
  const [amountOfItemsValue, changeamountOfItems] = useState(() =>
    initialValue()
  );
  const [surchargeFee, changeSurchargeFee] = useState(0);
  const [distanceFee, changeDistanceFee] = useState(0);
  const [containerFee, changeContainerFee] = useState(0);
  const [click, changeClick] = useState(true);
  const [clickedState, changeClickedState] = useState(true);

  const changeClickidy = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    changeClick(false);
  };
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    changeCartValue(() => initialValue());
    changeDeliveryDistance(() => initialValue());
    changeamountOfItems(() => initialValue());
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{DATE_RN}</h1>
        <h1>Delivery Fee Calculator</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form">
          <Surcharge
            cartValue={cartValue}
            changeCartValue={changeCartValue}
            changeSurchargeFee={changeSurchargeFee}
          />
          <br></br>
          <Distance
            deliveryDistance={deliveryDistance}
            changeDeliveryDistance={changeDeliveryDistance}
            changeDistanceFee={changeDistanceFee}
          />
          <br></br>
          <NumberOfItems
            amountOfItemsValue={amountOfItemsValue}
            changeamountOfItems={changeamountOfItems}
            changeContainerFee={changeContainerFee}
          />
          <br></br>
          <label htmlFor="date">When to deliver </label>
          <br></br>
          <input
            type="date"
            id="date"
            className="date"
            min={DATE_RN}
            max="2022-12-31"
          ></input>
          <br></br>
          <input
            type="submit"
            value="Calculate delivery price"
            onClick={changeClickidy}
          ></input>
          <OverallResult
            surchargeFee={surchargeFee}
            distanceFee={distanceFee}
            containerFee={containerFee}
            click={click}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
export const MIN_SUR_VALUE = 10;
export const INITIAL_VALUE = 0;
export const MAX_DISTANCE = 10000;
export const BASE_FEE = 2;
export const FREE_SHIPPING = 100;
export const NORMAL_ITEMS = 4;
export const MAX_FEE = 15;
export const DD = String(new Date().getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
export const MM = String(new Date().getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0"); //January is 0!
export const YYYY = new Date().getFullYear();
export const DATE_RN = `${YYYY}-${MM}-${DD}`;
const week = [
  "Sunday",
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday",
];
export const STRING_DAY = week[new Date().getDay()];
export const TIME_RN = new Date().getHours();
export let RND1 = true;
```

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { INITIAL_VALUE, STRING_DAY, TIME_RN, MAX_FEE } from "../helper/helper";
function OverallResult(props) {
  const [total, changeTotal] = useState(() => INITIAL_VALUE);

  useEffect(() => {
    changeTotal(2 + props.surchargeFee);

    return total;
  }, [props.click]);
  console.log(total);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        Day is {STRING_DAY} time is : {TIME_RN}
      </h1>
      <h1>Delivery price : {total}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
export default OverallResult;
```

Comment: How about, instead of breaking rules, then yelling your apologies after the fact, you read the rules, follow them, and then you don't have to apologize, and no one has to fix your mess?

Answer (score 0):

It seems  there's no way to solve this without using useReducer and useContext.

Comment: It's not an anwser but a comment. Otherwise, you could give an example, a link or something else.

Comment: I'm working on it give me some time.